# Нужны ли специальные права доступа для чтения папки System32?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть рабочий скрипт, но проблема в том, что он не "умеет" читать папку System32. Связано ли это с правами доступа?

```
import os, fnmatch

dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')
while not os.path.isdir(dirpath): #проверка пути
    print('Такого каталога нет')
    dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')

filename = input('Имя файла: ')

path_f = []
for d,dirs,files in os.walk(dirpath):
    for f in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, filename):
            path = (os.path.join(d, f))
            print (path)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пользователь, запускающий скрипт должен в любом случае иметь доступ к файлам. Так что, либо запускай от имени Администратора, либо давай права. Лучше первый вариант в целях безопасности.

Comment: тут дело не в правах, тут нужно выполнить поиск через массив:

if dfdf in dfdf:

Comment: видны ли сообщения об ошибке, если в cmd.exe запустить и onerror параметр передать в `os.walk()`? Что `print('hosts' in os.listdir(r'C:\Windows\System32')` показывает?

Comment: print('hosts' in os.listdir(r'C:\Windows\System32') - интерпретатор предлагает что-то дописать.

Запуск через cmd.exe работает ВСЁ!

Comment: Прикол в том что в Python 3.3 работает, а в Python 3.4 - нет.